# Binary XML file line #17: Duplicate id , tag null, or parent id with another fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to insert a fragment to another and I’ve succeed to do this until I’ve lunch the main fragment for the first time it's working but when I’m trying to reload the fragment the app crash, and i have this error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #17: Duplicate id 0x7f070084, tag null, or parent id 0x7f070082 with another fragment for com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome`

**i have tried two solutions** : **the first one** is to override the `onDestroyView` method.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        PlaceholderFragment f = (PlaceholderFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.f);
        if (f != null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
```

**And the second one** is to make surf in the that the view is already exist and try to remove it before the new one display

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (v != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(v);
        }


        v =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homes, container, false); }
```

Even if the two solutions doesn’t work for me and still hove the problem please any other solutions can you propose

**The Main fragment XML Layout :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
android:id="@+id/fHome"
tools:context="com.example.user.unchained.HomesActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/homeList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/f"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/footer_home" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

**The fragment XML Layout :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:id="@+id/homeFooter"
tools:context="com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome">


<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="What's New ?"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/status"
android:id="@+id/watsN"
android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" | "
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="145dip"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Check In"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="165dip"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkin"
    android:id="@+id/checkIn"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" | "
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="265dip"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" Picture"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="290dip"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/camera"
    android:id="@+id/postPic"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use getChildFragmentManager. You **can't** use child fragment in XML.

For example how you should do:

```
     if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("settingsFragment") == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        settingsFragment = new FastSettingsFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.container, settingsFragment, "settingsFragment");
        ft.commit();
    }
```